# Angular JS two-way-binding doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I am not able to use two-way-binding in my controller. There is something strange but I don't understand it. My data structure is a javascript object containing an array of strings.

```
$scope.schedule = {
    schedule_name: "Test 123",
    schedule_id: 1234,
    dates: [{
        date: "2015-01-01"
    }, {
        date: "2015-02-01"
    }, {...}]
}
```

I retrieve the schedules from my database and place it in a list in the UI. The elements of the `$scope.scheduleList` are clickable. If the user clicks on a schedule element then it will appear on the screen with all properties of the schedule object.

I iterate over the dates array with `ng-repeat="date in schedule.dates"` and use the date-value in `ng-model="date.date"` like this.

My Problem is that the scope variable `schedule` won't be updated on any changes.
Here is an excerpt of my code:

```js
$scope.scheduleList = [];
CommonDataService.get(URL).then(function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].dates.forEach(function(value, key) {
      data[i].dates[key] = {date: $filter("date")(value, "EEE, dd.MM.yyyy")};
    });
    data[i].schedule_name = data[i].schedule_name.substr(4);
  }
  $scope.scheduleList = data;
});

$scope.schedule = {};
$scope.showSchedules = function(schedule) {
    $scope.schedule = schedule;
}

...

$scope.save = function() {
  console.log($scope.schedules);
  //CommonDataService.add(URL, $scope.schedules).then(function(response) {
  //    console.log(response);
  //});
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body data-ng-app="rwk">
...
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6" data-ng-repeat="date in schedule.dates track by $index" data-ng-if="key !== 'schedule_id' && key !== 'schedule_name'">
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <p class="input-group pull-left">
          <input data-rwk-datepicker data-format="D, dd.mm.yyyy" id="{{$index}}" type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="date.date" data-ng-required="true" />
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am very lucky if anyone could help me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you applying `ng-app`, in the body or html tag? It appears you have forgotten to use the `ng-app` directive, because it appears to be rendering your HTML label content literally. This is usually the case when Angular is not told what part of the DOM to govern.

Comment: The scope variable may well be updated, but angular may not be picking up on it unless you notify it. If you update it asynchronously in a way that angular doesn't detect, then it won't know and can't update everything else. Look into `$scope.$apply` and `$timeout`. Could that be it...?

Comment: which changes are you referring to? UI changes of dates or service request changes?

Comment: How are `$scope.schedules` and `$scope.scheduleList` related? It's unclear from your post how they are linked (or if they are supposed to be the same)

Comment: @KarlAnderson `ng-app` is declareted in the body tag. 

@deceze I tried `$timeout` already but it doesn't work.

@charlietfl If the user change a date in the UI the scope variable schedule should be updated.

@JohnDrouhard `$scope.schedule` is on object of `$scope.scheduleList` which is passed to `$scope.schedule` when the user clicks an schedule list item. See edited explanation above.

Comment: What if you change ng-model to use: `ng-model="schedule.dates.date[$index]"`?

Comment: What is the `rwk-datepicker` directive doing? I assume that is updating the model when the user chooses a date. Care to show us that code, nothing else seems wrong at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely calling the `showSchedules()` function from outside angular's scope. You need to tell angular to update the bindings by wrapping the function body in `$scope.$apply(...)`:

```
$scope.schedule = {};
$scope.showSchedules = function(schedule) {
    $scope.$apply(
        $scope.schedule = schedule;
    );
}
```

You could wrap the call to `showSchedules` in a `$scope.$apply(...)` call as well.

Comment: Thanks, I modified your solution a bit and it worked!